# DOCX to PDF works after saving file only [JAVA]

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

The code provided bellow kinda works, the problemn i'm trying to solve is that i'm already able to save my docx localy. When im trying to covert it to pdf, i get blank pages or pages with only the docx header. But when i open the file manualy with Libre office or free office and save it without doing any alteration, and run the conversion again, the file converts perfectly just how i needed it. Anyone know why this happens and how could i replicate that behavior without having to actually opeing and saving the file, since i need to do all this processes programaticaly?

Im trying to covert a DOCX to PDF using:

```xml
<dependency>      
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>           
    <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>  
</dependency>
```

So far my code is:

```java
public byte[] converterXmlToDocx(Long idModeloDocumento) throws Docx4JException {
    try {
        byte[] gzipXml = buscarModeloDocumento(idModeloDocumento);
        byte[] xmlData = descompactarGzip(gzipXml);

        WordprocessingMLPackage pkg = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new    ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData));

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pkg.save(outputStream);

        //saves file localy
        String outputFilePath = "src/main/resources/test1.docx";
        File outputDocxFile = new File(outputFilePath);
        pkg.save(outputDocxFile);

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (Docx4JException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Docx4JException("Erro converting xml to docx", e);
    }
}


public void convertLOCAL(String docxFilePath, String pdfFilePath) {
    try {
        FileInputStream docxFile = new FileInputStream(docxFilePath);
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(docxFile);

        FileOutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath);
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, pdfFile, options);

        docxFile.close();
        pdfFile.close();

        System.out.println("Sucess");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException("Conversion Error", ex);
    }
}
```

What i do above is generating the docx file with the first method them converting it using the second method in my controller, passing input docx path and output pdf path.

Comment: So, the problem could be in the way DOCX is written on the disk converting from XML. If that DOCX is opened and saved as-is, then DOCX to PDF works. That means, the problem is in the DOCX generation. Why is `converterXmlToDocx()` using `pkg.save()` twice? Can't you do it with just once. Maybe just write it in `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then use that itself to write it to the disk. Not do `pkg.save()` again. Maybe `save` internally sets something in the first `save` call, which prevents it from writing the file on the disk when you call it the second time?

Comment: Thank you for the input. I wish i could find a way to understand what differs from the generated file to the same generated file after being opened and saved as-is.  I'm using 2 pkg.save cause the second save is part of commented code, to be used only for testing, in "production" im using only the stream to convert to pdf, and having the same result as converting the local file

Comment: What is calling converterXmlToDocx and convertLOCAL?  Is the input to converterXmlToDocx FlatOPC XML?  You can compare the document.xml portions of before and after.